# NodeJS script works fine on macOS but not on Windows

Tags: node.js, macos, powershell, cmd

I am trying to run a Node project that was created by someone using a Mac, but when I run `npm run start` it errors out with the message:

`npm ERR! missing script: clean;`

The error occurs in both CMD and Powershell.

I would guess that this is a syntax issue because in our package.json there is a script with the code `"npm run clean; npm run build"`; I assume that on Mac it treats the semicolon as a separator between two commands, while on Windows it seems to treat the semicolon as part of the word "clean" and attempts to run the script "clean;", which doesn't exist.

Is there a way to get this script to run on my computer without changing the project? If not, is there a way to change the project so that the same script will work on both Mac and Windows?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run `build` after `clean` use `&&` to run the commands sequentially.

`npm run clean && npm run build`

Comment: I don't think `&&` works in PowerShell. Try a semi-colon `;` or pipe instead `|`

Comment: Not in PowerShell 5.1 or earlier. Unable to confirm for later versions

Comment: Works in 5.1, build 17134

Comment: `&&` works great in CMD, PowerShell, and the mac terminal.